# Cassandra batch statement delete after insert not inserting for same primay key

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-driver

Here is my scenario, consider my table has cloumns `id` primary key and `clusterkey` cluster key. I want to delete one record falling under primary key and insert new record with same primary key but different cluster key. In this case, all the time it looks like insert is not happening due to some concurrency? Tried using Timestamp, but same issue.

```
const query1 = 'delete from table where id=? and clusterkey=?';
const query2 = 'INSERT INTO table (id, clusterkey, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
const queries = [
   { query: query1, params: ['1', '3'] },
   { query: query2, params: ['1', '8', 'GoodName'] } 
];
client.batch(queries, { prepare: true }, function (err) {
   console.log(err, 'done')
});
```

Using Timestamp

```
const query1 = 'delete from table where id=? and clusterkey=? using timestamp ?';
const query2 = 'INSERT INTO table (id, clusterkey, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?) using timestamp ?';
const queries = [
   { query: query1, params: ['1', '3', Date.now() * 1000] },
   { query: query2, params: ['1', '8', 'GoodName', Date.now() * 1000] } 
];
client.batch(queries, { prepare: true }, function (err) {
   console.log(err, 'done')
});
```

Table Info:

```
create table sample (id text, group text, name text, PRIMARY KEY (id, group))
```

Query Results:

select result before batch

```
    id  |clusterkey |name 
----------------------------- 
    1   |3       |wrongname 
    2   |2       |Hello
```

After batch

```
    id  |clusterkey |name 
----------------------------- 
    2   |2       |Hello
```

Comment: Can you please provide the table structure for the first case `(id, clusterkey, name)`.

Comment: `create table sample (id text, group text, name text, PRIMARY KEY (id, group)) `

Comment: @PasupathiRajamanickam Can you do a select after this batch execution and provide the results?

Comment: @dilsingi updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You added those queries into a batch but possibly forget to execute these queries.

try using,

```
client.execute( queries, function (err, result) { 
     if (!err) {
         console.log("executed.");
     }
} );
```

Follow this links for more details: [Cassandra executing a query](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-apache-cassandra-and-nodejs)

Comment: I'm not sure who is wrong here. http://datastax.github.io/nodejs-driver/features/batch/
says just `client.batch` will execute all. The one you mentioned to execute single query.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of @ruhul, if you have not executed batch then the delete also should not work. But you mentioned about insert only.

If not the mentioned case by @ruhul, then check if your cluster is consistent. It happens when cluster loses its consistency.

Run repair on  your cluster (`nodetool repair`) and check again.

Comment: I'm not sure who is wrong here. datastax.github.io/nodejs-driver/features/batch says just `client.batch` will execute all. The one you mentioned to execute single query. Ans yes, the above my code executed delete successfully.